# Optimising code structure of mutually-exclusive logical conditions that share common functionality?

Tags: logic

I have two mutually-exclusive logical conditions, *a* and *b*, that share some common code but have their own independent functionality. Whenever I have this problem, I combine these conditions into one IF block and then inefficiently query again, as below, but is there an alternative structure that is more optimal?

```
IF a OR b
  IF a
    // a-independent code
  ENDIF

  IF b
    // b-independent code
  ENDIF

  // shared code
ENDIF
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that the two conditions are mutually exclusive, you can:

1. replace `IF b` with `ELSE IF b`. In this way, the truth value for `b` won't be computed if you have already executed the first IF branch.
2. move the nested IF statements outside the `IF a OR b` check. This approach improves readability and, dependending on the programming language that you use, may lead to slightly more efficient code execution.

The final pseudocode is:

```
IF a
  // a-independent code
ENDIF

ELSE IF b
  // b-independent code
ENDIF

IF a OR b
  // shared code
ENDIF
```

Moreover, if computing `a` and `b` is expensive, ensure to do it only once by storing their value in suitable variables.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks a lot!